# Live updating data in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a call to my component like so:

```html
<app-jq-chart
    [title]="chart.title"
    [data]="dataValues"
    [xAxisConfig]="{
      range: dataRange.x,
      title: chart.axisLabels.x
    }"
    [yAxisConfig]="{
      range: dataRange.y,
      title: chart.axisLabels.y
    }"
    [lineColor]="'green'"
  ></app-jq-chart>
```

In the parent component, (whose partial template is shown above) a realtime service is sending websocket messages and in my websocket message handler, I take the message and extract data from it and store the new data in `dataValues`:

```js
  public subscribe() {
    this.rtdSubscription = this.rtdService.createObservableSocket().subscribe(
      {
        next: (message) => {
          // When a message comes in, if we have a handler for it, call that handler.
          const { payload, id } = JSON.parse(message);
          if (this.messageHandlers[id]) {
            this.messageHandlers[id].call(this, payload);  // the message handler stores the new dataValues
          }
        },
        error: err => console.warn(err),
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is the method from the service:

```js
 public createObservableSocket(): Observable<any> {
    const url: string = environment.rtdServer;
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    return new Observable(
      observer => {
        this.ws.onmessage = (event) => observer.next(event.data);
        this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
        this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
        return () => this.ws.close(1000, 'The user disconnected');
      }
    );
  }
```

In the template, how do I get `[data]="dataValues"` to update each time `dataValues` is changed in the template? I know it has something to do with observables...but those make my brain hurt so so bad.

Update: I've added this to my component constructor

```js
  constructor(private rtdService: RealtimedataService) {
    this.liveData = new Observable(observer =>
      observer.next(this.dataValues)
    )
  }
```

And changed the template to `[data]="liveData | async"`

The chart now says "no data available" which I believe is the jquery library's way of saying, well, the obvious. Which I take to mean that I've taken the correct first step in creating the `liveData` observable. I just haven't figured out how to put anything in it yet. I suspect that `liveData` should actually be observING something that calls what I currently have for its callback/handler.

Someone asked about where I'm currently updating dataValues:

```js
handleNewStreamFrame(payload) {
    // If the message is for a different stream, exit.
    if (payload.streamGuid !== this.streamGuid) {
      return;
    }

    // Store the new data
    // IF we're not paused,
    // OR we have requested an update.
    if (!this.paused || this.hasRequestedUpdatedRange) {
      this.dataValues = payload.dataPoints;
    }

    // Update the graph's range
    // IF we've received this frame in response to a request for a new range.
    if (this.hasRequestedUpdatedRange) {
      this.hasRequestedUpdatedRange = false;

      const { xRange, yRange } = payload;
      this.updateRangeFromFrame(xRange, yRange);
    }

    this.draw();
  }
```

This is a websocket message handler. Note the `draw()` call at the end: this component initially used its own canvas to display the graph, calling the canvas drawing methods itself as you see. Now the `app-jq-chart` (a wrapper I wrote for the jquery library jqChart) is doing the drawing, with the data I'm sending it. In other words, my initial implementation was a great way to procrastinate learning how to do all this correctly!

Comment: perhaps you could look about the DOM pipe `[data]="dataValues | async"`. not sure it's the right syntax but just pointing into some direction. I think instead of using `dataValues` you should add the `Observable`

Comment: Can we see how you actually update `dataValues`?

Comment: Updated, @ConnorsFan

Comment: @JonathanTuzman I'm not sure to understand why do you have one `webSocket Observable` and one other `Observable`

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that (also I'm not sure what you mean). The data updating in the parent _component_ works great, it's just the matter of getting it, async/update/observed to the child component.

Comment: @JonathanTuzman what I mean is that `liveData` and `this.ws` are two distinct `Observable`, I never used webSockets but what seems to me logic is that there is no links between the two variables, so as a result you are not retrieving any value

Comment: Simply speaking, your WebSocket Observable should be piped directly to the component. This needs a bit of a refactoring but would be the more reactive way to do it. To get you started: Remove the `subscribe` method. Make the WebSocket Observable accessible to the parent component. Put everything you need to do in a `pipe(tap(...))` after the observable. Directly subscribe to the piped observable with `async`.

Comment: @ggradnig I feel like that's sort of what I'm doing, except it's being piped to the parent component? In the 2nd snippet of my post, the message is received in the parent component, it goes through a process that ends with assigning `this.dataValues`. I believe that's what you mean about piping it directly to the component. But maybe that's not  what you mean and maybe that's the crucial thing I'm missing. I don't want to deal with it in `app-jq-chart` code, I want to deal with the data in the parent component.

Comment: Do you use a different ChangeDetectionStrategy? Maybe OnPush? Are you sure that `this.dataValues = payload.dataPoints;` is called?